# Saving OOP PHP files as .class

Tags: php, oop

Quick question. Is it okay to save a PHP class file as myClass.class and include it in other "regular" .php files?

It works just fine in PHP 5.3, but I'm wondering if it is bad practice.

tl;dr:

```
useObjects.php
<? include('myClass.class');
$my_object_1 = new myClass();
?>

myClass.class
<?
//constructors and functions
?>
```

Thank you!

EDIT: This is just for my own organization.

Comment: it would work, but it would also allow people to view your code as `text/plain` if they know the path. Giving an attacker insight into any insecuritys

Comment: The ability to view oddly-named source files as text/plain is not a concern if you have them outside document_root, which you should.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, this is in a nonpublic directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only technical reason not to do this is if the web server is not configured to parse `.class` files as PHP scripts, and if a file is beneath the document root and accessed via the browser, it will display PHP source code to the end user exposing source code or sensitive data like database connection details.

Beyond that, it's a matter of convention. And while PHP doesn't have too many conventions to speak of, `.class` is a pretty unusual one.  `*.class.php` is fairly common, however.

Comment: Thanks, I'll still with the regular .php extension.

Comment: require() and include() inherently evaluate. You don't need to configure the server to parse them as PHP. (Sorry, to clarify, this statement was intended as a clarification. :)

Comment: Also note that if you don't use *.php, then source highlighting (as in vim or NetBeans) won't work out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

It's unusual, since `.class` is not necessarily a common PHP convention, but other than that there's no technical reason against it.

Comment: That, and `.class` is common with Java, so the file naming could cause some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only thing that really matters is [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md). You should name classes so it works with that standard.

- `\Doctrine\Common\IsolatedClassLoader` = `Doctrine/Common/IsolatedClassLoader.php`
- `\Symfony\Core\Request` = `Symfony/Core/Request.php`
- `\Zend\Acl` = `Zend/Acl.php`
- `\Zend\Mail\Message` = `Zend/Mail/Message.php`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with using it but. Conventionally i would prefer to use .inc with means include.